# VBA Accessing data structure

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have this really complicated data structure which I am trying to access. The reason I set it up like this is because I want to have a structure of each report containing all the questions for that report with all the data for each question. Please see the code below to understand what I am doing.

```
Dim master As New Dictionary      
Dim child As New Dictionary
```

this happens for each question in a report. Note in the end coll1-coll6 is what I want to print out

```
'coll# is a collection 
child.Add ID, Array(coll1, coll2, coll3, coll4, coll5, coll6)
```

this happens for each report in a list of reports to be created

```
master.Add reportNumber, child
```

Now I pass in each report one by one by doing this

```
master.key(i)
```

Given a report from the master.key(i) I want to be able to access the Array in child which contains all the collections

```
For Each key In reportData.Keys
     Debug.Print reportData(key).Item(1).Item(1)
Next key
```

The above piece of code is me trying to print out the data from inside a report inside a question inside a collection for one of the questions

PS. I know this may seem convoluted but I saw it as the best solution to store a list of reports with all there data to make automatic reports.

In summary my question is how do I access my data which is inside a collection in a array.

Suggestions are welcome as to a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish. Which is essentially a frame work where I can automatically create reports.

I have changed the Array(coll1, ... , coll6) to a string to see if I can access it and it printed out correctly. So it looks like I am having troubles accessing the Array(coll1, ... , coll6)

Comment: In the text you mention "collection" but your code uses Dictionaries and arrays. Is `reportData` the same as `master`  ?

Comment: No reportData is master.key(i)

Comment: The dictionary reportData contains an Array of collections

Comment: Sorry I totally missed the comment about the array contents being a collection.  You can't access an array element using `Item()` though - you'd need `yourArrayHere(0)` to access the first item so something like `reportData(key)(0).Item(1)`

Comment: Debug.Print "Comment is: " & reportData(key)(counter).Item(1) Gives me an invalid procedure call error

Comment: This is *really* begging for an object oriented solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is close to what you want:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim Master As New Dictionary
    Dim child As New Dictionary, km, kc
    Dim col1 As New Collection, col2 As New Collection

    col1.Add "Hello"
    col1.Add "World"
    col2.Add "Blue"
    col2.Add "Green"

    child.Add "ID01", Array(col1, col2)

    Master.Add "Key01", child

    For Each km In Master.Keys
        Debug.Print "Master key:", km          '>> Key01
        For Each kc In Master(km)
            Debug.Print "    Child key:", kc   '>> ID01
            Debug.Print , Master(km)(kc)(0)(1) '>> Hello
            Debug.Print , Master(km)(kc)(0)(2) '>> World
            Debug.Print , Master(km)(kc)(1)(1) '>> Blue
            Debug.Print , Master(km)(kc)(1)(2) '>> Green
        Next kc
    Next km

End Sub
```